Is there a way to group aggregations by message?
I'm trying to set up a graylog dashboard, but whenever I add the message field to any widget, I get this error

While retrieving data for this widget, the following error(s) occurred:
OpenSearch exception [type=search_phase_execution_exception, reason=all shards failed].

